# Android URLConnection Post Local

Tags: java, php, android, url, local

I have a Java Netbeans Application that makes use of the URLConnection Class, the netbeans project works just fine posting variables to the below local .php path:

```
    String URLinput = "http://localhost/urlct2ws/";
```

I need the same capabilities reflected on my Java Android Application, however this page doesn't exist locally on my android device, I'm assuming it therefore is crashing.

Since this path refers to a folder created by XAMP I'm not sure how/if these capabilities translate to an android application, or what the newly described path should look like.

Thank you for your time to read and respond to my post, any guidance is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the Android Application will eventually connect to an actual Web-server, I would just like to establish this connection for testing purposes.

Comment: If your PC & the Android is connected to the same network, just replace localhost with your PC internal IP. Obviously test it first from the Android browser

Comment: Like `String URLinput = "http://192.198.2.23/urlct2ws/";`. With the local ip address of your pc where the service is running on.